# How to create filterable menu using arrays and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter, filtering

Please can you help me create a filter using the filter menu below to filter the menu list?

Filter Menu:

- potato
- chicken
- rice
- cucumber
- fish
- ham
- milk

Meals List:

```
<div class="potato chicken rice cucumber fish">Meal 1</div>
<div class="ham milk cucumber fish">Meal 2</div>
<div class="chicken">Meal 3</div>
<div class="potato  fish">Meal 4</div>
<div class="potato rice cucumber fish">Meal 5</div>
```

So basically, for example, if a user selects "chicken", I want it to add `chicken` into the array(filter) so that it will only show the meals from the menus list with similar classes as the filter array, in this case "chicken". Then if the user selects "fish", I want the same thing repeated so that it will only show meals with shared classes in the array, in this case "fish" and "chicken".

Answer (score 2):

This example uses checkboxes for filter options. hope this helps...
http://jsfiddle.net/ahmon_abilar/yVNP6/

```js
$('input[name=filter]').on('click', function(){
    var strFilter = "";
    $.each($('input[name=filter]:checked'), function(i){
        strFilter += "." + $(this).val();
    });
    $('div').hide();
    $('div'+strFilter).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn67S/7/

click the button to add/remove the element to the filter array. The result is the menus that contain at least one of the elements in the array.

I hope you can do something with this.

EDIT: here's the code:

```
var filterarray = [];
$(".filterbutton").click(function() {
    var tempFilter = $(this).attr("value");
    if (filterarray.indexOf(tempFilter) == -1) {
    filterarray.push(tempFilter);
    } else {      
     filterarray.splice(filterarray.indexOf(tempFilter),1); 
    }
    if (filterarray.length > 0) {
        filter();
    } else {
        showAllElements();
    }
});

function filter() {
    var selector = "";
    for (i = 0; i < filterarray.length; i ++) {
        selector += "." + filterarray[i];
        if (i!=filterarray.length - 1) {
         selector += ", "; // Remove this line if you want results contain all ingredients in filter array
        }
    }
    if (filterarray.length > 0) {
        hideAllMenus();
        $("#menus").find(selector).show(); 
    }    
}

function hideAllMenus() {
    $(".menu").hide();
}

function showAllElements() {
    $(".menu").show();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="potato" class="filterbutton"></input>
<input type="button" value="chicken" class="filterbutton"></input>
<input type="button" value="rice" class="filterbutton"></input>
<input type="button" value="cucumber" class="filterbutton"></input>
<input type="button" value="fish" class="filterbutton"></input>
<input type="button" value="ham" class="filterbutton"></input>
<input type="button" value="milk" class="filterbutton"></input>   


<div id="menus">
<div class="menu potato chicken rice cucumber fish">Meal 1</div>
<div class="menu ham milk cucumber fish">Meal 2</div>
<div class="menu chicken">Meal 3</div>
<div class="menu potato  fish">Meal 4</div>
<div class="menu potato rice cucumber fish">Meal 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's amazing of you much appreciated. I'm playing around with it and it's a very good start for me to start using selectors and arrays. Looking forward to see more.

Comment: Can you also do if class already inside filter remove it please?

Comment: wow your code is amazing and solved the problem... can you please help me create a button to clear filter? thank you so much

Comment: I think you should now be able to find this yourself. A quick google search for 'delete elements in array javascript' should learn you how to clear the filter. Then you can call showAllMenus function(). Dont forget to mark this as an answer if this helped you.

Comment: But... Here's what you've asked with a small extra: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn67S/7/

Comment: man u r amazing thanks... much love to u <3 < no homo

Comment: Why is the first line of the HTML indented?